# Using BufferedWriter with JFileChooser to set save directory

Tags: java, jfilechooser, bufferedwriter

For my ongoing project at work I have been asked to add a feature to my program. Currently the program allows a user to upload a file which is then manipulated. After being reformatted the file is saved into a new .ACH file (which is just a text file with strict formatting standards).

Currently the user is able to upload an ACH file from anywhere on their computer using this code:

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("ACH Files", "ach");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Please choose ACH file to upload");
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
```

Later in the program buffered reader/writer make edits to the file and then save it to the new location using this code:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(chooser.getCurrentDirectory()+"//NachaOutput.ACH"));
```

Finally, the user is informed of the file name and save location using this code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Output file saved as NachaOutput.ach to " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
```

As you can see, the new file is saved to the same directory that the file was uploaded from. My manager has requested that I allow the user the choice of a directory to save the new file to. (The file name is not imporant nor does it need to be set by the user, only the directory).

I have tried and tried to research how to do this, to no avail. The only guide that I found was very lengthy and I'll confess was too complicated for me to understand. I have attempted to create a new JFileChooser and allow the user to set the directory only and use the code:

```
int saveVal = chooser2.showSaveDialog(chooser2);
```

However I find that when I attempt to pull the saved directory later like this:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(chooser2.getCurrentDirectory()+"//NachaOutput.ACH"
```

the file is saved to my computers standard directory. (C://Users or something to that affect.)

Is there a basic way that I can give the user a simple input to select a directory and then utilize it with the bw on the line I shown above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a basic way that I can give the user a simple input to
>   select a directory

The basic way to do this is:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

The rest maybe not that obvious (you have to ask for the chosen *file* to get the directory):

```
int returnVal = chooser.showDialog(chooser, "Directory to save");
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile());
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO SO much! I spent quite a deal of time on that this morning at least two hours.

You were 100% correct also in why it was not working for me. The problem was that I was using .getSelectedDirectory rather than .getSelectedFile. It works perfectly now.

Thanks again!